# Composer reinstalls the same bundle in Symfony project

Tags: php, git, azure, composer-php

I haven't seen any thread talking about this issue, this is my first question that I make.

So I have been having a problem with my PreDeployment remote server based on Microsoft Azure. Everytime I pull the project on git, the bundles `ramsay/uuid` `phansys/getid`seems not installed, indeed the bundle is not mentioned when I do a `composer show` and I have to do a `composer install` everytime to reinstall the same bundles.

This problem also occurs on my Deployment Server which is on a different Microsoft Azure server too. They both have the same git. However this one has to reinstall everytime 25 bundles more than the PreDeployment.

This process always make the deployment process take a lot of time on both PreDeployment and Deployment. I often lose half a day of work because of this.

The composer.lock and composer.json are up to date and shared on the git otherwise the bundle wouldn't reinstall everytime.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is your vendor/ folder also commited to the git repository? does `composer show` output anything directly after a fresh pull?

Comment: the vendor/folder is not commited to the git repository. The composer show outputs bundles installed, except the ones that misses(but was already installed before the previous fresh pull). He then reinstalls them.